# In Angular6, what is the way to simulate receiving 4xx and 5xx responses from server

Tags: angular-test

I am using HttpClient’s post method to send messages to the server. To test it, I want to simulate receiving 404 and 500 responses from the server. What is the way to simulate receiving 4xx and 5xx error messages in Angular6?  As far as I know, I cannot use spyOn().and.returnValue because this will not simulate server error and will not trigger the error code handler passes to the post method.

Comment: There's a whole section of the docs on testing services that use `HttpClient`: https://angular.io/guide/http#testing-http-requests

Comment: Could you share the unit you're trying to test, perhaps possibly along with the test you've written so far?

Comment: Thanks. I think flush with error message is what I need. I will check

Comment: @jonsharpe - the link was helpful. `flush` and `error` methods of `TestMessage` can do the trick. Happy to accept your answer if you could make your comment an  answer